# Single parent travelling with minors

Tags: international-travel, minors

Single parents travelling internationally with minor children may need a notarized letter from the other parent. My husband/the father of my children passed away. What should I bring on our trip to Italy? Thanks!

Comment: It is rather hard to answer this without knowing which country. Perhaps edit that in?

Comment: Sorry for you loss. Anecdotal: My wife, kids and myself have been travelling in all possible combinations when the kids were minors and we never had or needed a letter when it was just one of us parents. As minors our kids have also traveled occasionally on their own without any parent, and no letter was required. Granted, they always had good travel documents on their own and "easy" nationalities.

Comment: Good question. We do use the notarized letter of consent often but presumably you could get a similar letter saying that you are the sole remaining guardian of your children. Where to get that depends on applicable laws where you live.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind is the death certificate.

Comment: For the USA, a certified death certificate would be advisable.

Just heard a friend-of-a-friend story of someone denied boarding at an American airport for lack of other-parent permission. I, myself, was warned once; I had my wife's itinerary (separate flight) as back-up.

Comment: I would suggest carrying the children's Birth Certificates showing mum and dad's names.

Comment: What is your and the childrens nationality? It is often the home country that checks for permission to travel from parents.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.